# Trying to apply a Rastermask and Reproject Landsat images but I keep getting: RuntimeError: Object: Error in accessing environment <extent>

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst, extents

I am new to python and I´m trying to set the extent but I am having trouble and can't fix the error.

```
from time import gmtime, strftime

import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *

arcpy.CheckOutExtension("spatial")

WorkingDirectory = r"C:\Users\djurado\Documents\NALCMS\2020\wet_composite_2015"
SnapRasterMask = WorkingDirectory + os.sep + "mex_boundary" + os.sep + "boundary_raster.img"

arcpy.env.cellSize = SnapRasterMask
arcpy.env.extent = SnapRasterMask
arcpy.env.snapRaster = SnapRasterMask
rawrasters = WorkingDirectory + os.sep + "raw"

arcpy.env.workspace = rawrasters
workspace = arcpy.env.workspace

rasters = arcpy.ListRasters("*", "tif")

for raster in rasters:
    ### Input File Location
    InRaster = workspace + os.sep + raster
    PrjName = raster[:-4]
    ### Set the location and name of your output files
    PrjRaster = WorkingDirectory + os.sep + "projected" + os.sep + PrjName +"_prj.img"
    
    ### Process: Project Raster
    print (" Projecting... " + InRaster)
    arcpy.ProjectRaster_management(InRaster, PrjRaster, "PROJCS['WGS84_Lambert_Azimuthal_Equal_Area',GEOGCS['GCS_WGS_1984',DATUM['D_WGS_1984',SPHEROID['WGS_1984',6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0.0],UNIT['Degree',0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION['Lambert_Azimuthal_Equal_Area'],PARAMETER['false_easting',0.0],PARAMETER['false_northing',0.0],PARAMETER['central_meridian',-100.0],PARAMETER['latitude_of_origin',45.0],UNIT['Meter',1.0]]", "CUBIC", "30 30", "", "", "GEOGCS['GCS_WGS_1984',DATUM['D_WGS_1984',SPHEROID['WGS_1984',6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0.0],UNIT['Degree',0.0174532925199433]]", "NO_VERTICAL")


### End of script
```

After running the Module this error appears,

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\djurado\Documents\NALCMS\2015\GEE\scripts\02_mexico_prj_original (1).py", line 33, in 
> arcpy.env.extent = SnapRasterMask
> File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.6\ArcPy\arcpy\geoprocessing_base.py", line 541, in set_
> self[env] = val
> File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.6\ArcPy\arcpy\geoprocessing_base.py", line 601, in **setitem**
> ret_ = setattr(self._gp, item, value)
> RuntimeError: Object: Error in accessing environment

Comment: Are you sure that your `SnapRasterMask`, C:\Users\djurado\Documents\NALCMS\2020\wet_composite_2015\mex_boundary\boundary_raster.img exists? What do you see when you add `print(SnapRasterMask, arcpy.Exists(SnapRasterMask))`?

Comment: First compute extent of naskraster, assign env.extent equal to it.

Comment: @faith_dur I have check the existing files as you suggested and this error appears now> `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\djurado\Documents\NALCMS\2020\copias_scripts\02_mexico_prj_copia.py", line 51, in <module>
    for raster in rasters:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
>>> `